# Hide GPU from an app, and force the program to use CPU to do software rendering?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, gpu, rendering

I have a somewhat old version of some photo editing software that is having issues with my current video card.

Is there a way to hide my GPU from this program in order to force the CPU to do software rendering, so the program works again?

I was thinking maybe there exists a command line-based program I can download that hides my GPU, that I can run before starting the photo editing software.

I am using Windows 10 64-bit Enterprise

Comment: @K7AAY i edited the question

Comment: Which GPU is that?

Comment: @K7AAY I have verified on my own that the GPU is the problem. I just need to find a way to force the program to use software rendering so I don't have to disable my GPU in the Device Manger every time

Comment: Once an accurate answer is provided, you can mark an answer as useful by clicking on the checkmark at left. This helps others know what works.

Comment: @as soon as i test your answer and it works i'll mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

The April 2018 Update from Microsoft adds this ability. Version 1803 provides per-app GPU management: Go to Settings | Display then click the  **Graphics settings** link at the very bottom of the page to start tinkering.

Do you have Version 1803, the April 2018 Update?  Check with  <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>winver<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you don't have Version 1803, accepting the update is called for.